# Thunderbird opens HTTPS links in Chromium, instead of default browser

Tags: thunderbird, default-browser

I've set the following data in Thunderbird's config editor:

```
network.protocol-handler.app.http;x-www-browser
network.protocol-handler.app.https;x-www-browser
```

As soon as I did this, *http:* links are opened with `x-www-browser` (which currently links Google Chrome), but *https:* links are still opened in my old default browser, Chromium.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Launch Thunderbird.
2. Click on the menu button.

   [image: M]
3. Click on Preferences.

   [image: Pr1]
4. Again click on Preferences.

   [image: PR2]
5. Then goto the Advanced tab.

   [image: AT]
6. Click on Config Editor.

   [image: CE]
7. Pass through the Warranty by clicking "I'll be careful, I promise!".

   [image: W]
8. Then search for "network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http". And change the value to true by double-clicking both the entry.

   [image: http]
9. Then, search for "network.protocol-handler.warn-external.ftp". And change the value to true by double-clicking both the entry.

   [image: ftp]

Now, you will be able to launch your default browser on clicking on any link.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Didn't work for me, Thunderbird still launches Chromium in spite of my configuration.